# How to separate page class and test class python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I want to separate all web element page (Xpath) in different class with test, but when I create page class it needs webdriver than I declare webdriver like this:

```
class HomePage(constant.Constant,page.Page):

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome (r'C:\Users\USER\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver')
        self.masukBtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath ("//button[contains(text(),'Masuk')]")
        self.emailTxtField = driver.find_element_by_xpath ("//input[@placeholder='Email']")
```

then in test class i define web driver to hit url :

```
def setUp(self):
    self.driver.get("https://www.gramedia.com/")
def test_loginPositive(self):
    print('test_loginPositive')
    hp = homepage.HomePage()
    hp.masukBtn.click()
    hp.emailTxtField.send_keys(constant.Constant.EMAIL)
```

It doesn't work. Chrome was running 2 times, and I got:

```
error Traceback (most recent call last)
```

My question is, how to define webdriver so I can use in test class. Thank you.

Comment: Please put the full error